# How do I install redis 5.0.14 using homebrew

Tags: macos, redis, homebrew

**I need to install redis version 5.0.14 on my mac using brew.**

I have tried multiple ways like brew install redis@5.0.14, redis@5.0, redis@50, redis@5 but nothing seems to work!!

I was able to find out on https://formulae.brew.sh/ that the options that can be installed using brew are redis, redis@4.0, redis@3.2 . But I need to install redis 5.0.14 or basically above 5.0.6 because that is the version we have on our production. Can anyone help me out on this?

I have seen a way [here](https://gist.github.com/czarneckid/1536207/d643929cd28cbf853275ee0ba495975a42779549) that suggests to checkout specific homebrew formulae version but that would become too messy if something goes wrong. I would prefer a straight forward way if there is one.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the Redis version you require is not available via **homebrew**, your question is unanswerable. However, given how good **docker** is on macOS, I have taken to using that rather than **homebrew** for lots of version-related problems.

With **docker**:

- I can pull any version I want,
- it's all isolated from my core macOS,
- just as performant,
- readily deletable,
- simple to have many versions,
- switchable between versions,
- repeatable across platforms and
- configurable by script.

Official image [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis).

---

So, in concrete terms, you could run Redis 5.0.14 as a daemon like this:

```
docker run --name some-redis -d redis:5.0.14
```

and then connect to that same container and run `redis-cli` inside it like this:

```
docker exec -it some-redis redis-cli PING
PONG
```

---

Or you could run Redis in the container but expose its port 6379 as port 65000 to your regular macOS applications like this:

```
docker run --name some-redis -p 65000:6379 -d redis:5.0.14
```

Then it is accessible to your macOS applications, such as `redis-cli` like this:

```
redis-cli -p 65000 info | grep redis_version
redis_version:5.0.14
```

Answer (score 0):

The version you're looking for is not available on brew unfortunately.

```
bruno@pop-os ~> brew info --json redis | jq -r '.[].versioned_formulae[]'
redis@4.0
redis@3.2
```

You could get the source code from here: https://github.com/redis/redis/releases/tag/5.0.14

extract it to some directory, to run Redis with the default configuration just type:

```
% cd src
% ./redis-server
```

If you want to provide your redis.conf, you have to run it using an additional
parameter (the path of the configuration file):

```
% cd src
% ./redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
```

It is possible to alter the Redis configuration by passing parameters directly
as options using the command line. Examples:

```
% ./redis-server --port 9999 --replicaof 127.0.0.1 6379
% ./redis-server /etc/redis/6379.conf --loglevel debug
```

All the options in redis.conf are also supported as options using the command
line, with exactly the same name.

Optionally you could use Docker, `docker run --name some-redis -d redis:5.0.14`

Answer (score -2):

```
brew update
brew install redis
```

To have launchd start redis now and restart at login:

```
brew services start redis
```

To stop it, just run:

```
brew services stop redis
```

Test if Redis server is running.

```
redis-cli ping
```

Comment: This actually doesn't answer OP, as the specific version he's looking for is not available on brew.